# Adding foreign key constraints to a table fails although all values are NULL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an InnoDB table that I have altered to add a nullable `parent_id` column that can refers to its own `id` column. This `parent_id` column is just created and full of `NULL`.

I want to add a foreign key constrain from `parent_id` to `id`. I typed

```
alter table foo add foreign key (parent_id) references foo(id);
```

but it returned

> ERROR 1823 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint 'testdb/foo_ibfk_1' to system tables

If I try to execute the same command again, it now returns

> ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table './testdb/foo' already exists

If I name the constrain, the error changes

```
alter table foo add constraint my_constrain_name_ifk foreign key  (parent_id) references foo(foo_id);
```

> ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './testdb/#sql-404e_4c428' to './testdb/foo' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I think the problem might be that the table foreign keys have been messed up (possibly before I started updating `foo` with `parent_id`). In particular, although I don't see any foreign key constrain related to table `foo` in `information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`, I *do* see `testdb/foo` showing up in the `FOR_NAME` column of `information_schema.INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN`.

Running `mysqlcheck` on `testdb` did not return any error.

Could you please advise on how you would proceed? I think it has to be some sort of DB corruption, as the foreign key constrain should be enforceable at this point. Is it safe to remove rows from `INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN`?

EDIT

If I recreate the table from scratch in another DB, the command above goes well, so the error I have either comes from the fact that the original schema is not empty, or that it is corrupted.

Comment: *ERROR 1823 .. ERROR 1050 ..* Extremely strange - the error messages does not match the queries. What if you specify the table name completely: ```alter table testdb.foo add foreign key (parent_id) references testdb.foo (id);```? *ERROR 1025* Show complete table definition.

Comment: @Akina I get exactly the same error by specifying the schema.